# Karma-jasmine and beforeAll/afterAlll hooks in Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I would like to be able to use `beforeAll` and `afterAll` hooks in my application, but I am unable to do so with karma-jasmine. I'm aware I need to modify my boot.js file, but that's provided by the library. How would I set a beforeAll callback in the `karma.conf.js` file?

Comment: not sure how beforeAll callback can have any relevant with karma.conf.js ? according to the [documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html) : `The beforeAll function is called only once before all the specs in describe are run, and the afterAll function is called after all specs finish. These functions can be used to speed up test suites with expensive setup and teardown`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a callback in `karma.conf.js`... The [Karma Docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html) show all possible configuration options and there is no option to set a callback.